# Does the word “see out” make sense in this context

Tags: word-usage, word-request

“He was transferred to another branch to see out the last few remaining years of his career.”

Also, what are some synonyms for “see out” that can be used here?

Comment: If a man of 80 buys 5 pairs of shoes at a bargain price, he might say 'these will see me out'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense. It means to complete or finish something.

Answer (score 1):

It means to ***continue*** to do something (=to work) **until it (=his career) is finished.**

*Out* often means ***to the end*** or ***completely***. Sort out (sort things until they are in order), clear out something (remove unwanted things until it's tidy), wear out something (use it so much that it becomes damaged), run out of something (there is nothing left).